# React: date and date format in api preview and console of that api response are showing different

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, date, timezone

I have React-Node application. I am calling one node api which giving me correct datetime format in Developer's Network tab's preview. But when I console that api response, I am getting datetime in Local format.

**Preview** of api - Note `eventStartDate` format

[image]

**Console** of api response - Note `eventStartDate` format

[image]

I am not getting why those date are coming in different format and are not matching though api is same in Network and console.

What will be the cause of this?

Please guide and help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your API returns JSON with a string containing a UTC-based ISO8601/RFC3339 timestamp:

```json
"eventStartDate":"2024-03-18T03:30:00.000Z"
```

That's perfect.

You then parse that JSON somewhere in your app code, replacing it with a JavaScript `Date` object - i.e. `new Date(eventStartDate)`.  That's fine too.  (Possibly this is done automatically by your framework/library code.)

Internally to the `Date` object, the corresponding timestamp of `1710732600000` is stored.  That's the *only* value encapsulated by the `Date` object.

Then later, you are *displaying* the object in the console.  The browser you're running (Chrome, etc.) is choosing to display the local-time equivalent of that timestamp - as if you called `toString()` on the `Date` object.  That's why you see:

```
eventStartDate: Sun Mar 17 2024 09:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Note that Eastern Time comes from *your computer* - not anything stored in value or in the `Date` object itself.  If I did the same thing in another time zone, I'd see a different local value representing the same instant in time.

This is just how the `Date` object works.

You said you needed the UTC time, and I presume in the same ISO8601/RFC3339 format, so call `eventStartDate.toISOString()`.

Comment: I got what you are trying to explain, but why is eventEndDate displayed the same?

Comment: That totally depends on your own code.  Somewhere it's calling something like `eventStartDate = new Date(eventStartDate)` and not the same for `eventEndDate`.